# set theory, conjecture in sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

a) Let A = {c}, B = {a, b}, C = {b, d}, and U = {a, b, c, d, e, f}. Find A ∪ (Bc ∩ Cc) and (A ∪ Bc) ∩ (A ∪ Cc) showing each step of your calculation.

b) Let A = {1, 3, 7, 8}, B = {2, 3, 6, 7}, C = {4, 6, 7, 8}, and U = {1, 2, 3, …, 8} Find A ∪ (Bc ∩ Cc) and (A ∪ Bc) ∩ (A ∪ Cc) showing each step of your calculation.

**c) Based on the results in parts a and b, make a conjecture of an equality*

i have done parts (a) and (b) but have no idea how to do part (c).. This is part of my project. Please anyone help me out with this part, i will be thankful to that person.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have noticed that in both part a and part b $$A \cup (B^c \cap C^c) = (A \cup B^c) \cap (A \cup C^c)$$ Perhaps that's the conjecture; that that equation holds for **any** sets.

Do you know how you can prove it?

Comment: Thanks. Its been too tricky.. no i dont know how to prove it. if you share some more stuff then that would be so nice of you :)

Comment: Check out the distributive law of set algebra which states that $P \cup (R \cap S) = (P \cup R) \cap (P \cup S)$ for any sets $P, R, S$. That is essentially what you do here.

Comment: See [this](http://easycalculation.com/theorems/distributive-law.php) for the proof of the distributive law. You are simply applying that law in your problem.